# Duplicate row removal

Tags: c#, linq

First of all I will post what I have done so far:

```
from person in Persons
join customer in Customers on person.BusinessEntityID equals customer.PersonID
join salesOrderHeader in SalesOrderHeaders on customer.CustomerID equals salesOrderHeader.CustomerID
where salesOrderHeader.SubTotal > 1000
join address in Addresses on salesOrderHeader.BillToAddressID equals address.AddressID
where address.City == "Melton"
select new {
                person.FirstName,
                person.LastName,
                salesOrderHeader.SubTotal,
            address.City
       }
```

This query works perfectly only the problem is that I am getting back a duplicate row on the `firstname` and `lastname`. I could solve this by adding the `Distinct()` extension method already tried that and it works but I am very curios if it can be done without any extension method.

So how can I get the resulted table back without any duplicated rows on the `firstname` and `lastname`?

**EDIT**: In this case I recieve back something like this:

[image]

I would like to get back only one person of the same type with the total value that he spent.Sorry for not explaining myself better the first time around forgot to mention that I want to get back the total value of the person

Comment: If you have multiple people in there with the identical first and last name, if the same person has multiple sales orders, or if the same person has multiple addresses, you will have multiple results with the same `{FirstName, LastName}`. Are you sure it's not what leading to multiple rows?

Comment: I aggre with that and that is the case but I do not want to have ther orders from the same person twice even if there are two orders

Comment: What would be a sample output of this query that you want in case of duplicates?

Comment: In other words, **what do you want to happen in case of multiple SalesOrderHeaders**? The solution obviously depends on the answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a GroupBy and an aggregation.

```
from person in Persons
join customer in Customers on person.BusinessEntityID equals customer.PersonID
join salesOrderHeader in SalesOrderHeaders on customer.CustomerID equals salesOrderHeader.CustomerID
where salesOrderHeader.SubTotal > 1000
join address in Addresses on salesOrderHeader.BillToAddressID equals address.AddressID
where address.City == "Melton"
group salesOrderHeader by new { person.FirstName, person.LastName } into g //new
select new {
                g.Key.FirstName,
                g.Key.LastName,
                SubTotal = g.Sum(salesOrderHeader => salesOrderHeader.SubTotal),
            address.City
       }
```

GroupBy collapsed multiple rows into one, which is what you want here.

Comment: I have tryed your query  but it seems that for some reason in linqpad address is out of range in the select statement

Comment: Oh I overlooked that you also need the City. But the same technique applies to it - just modify my example code appropriately and it'll work. Let me know if you have further issues or questions.